# How to concatenate numaric code and string inside TextInput value using React Native

Tags: react-native, react-native-textinput

There are two variables like.

```
this.state={Amount=50, CurrencySymbol="&#x20B9;"}
```

TextInput Render

```
<TextInput value={this.state.CurrencySymbol + " " + this.state.Amount.toString()} editable={false}></TextInput>
```

but the Currency symbol is not showing.

Is there any way to print the currency symbol dynamically inside TextInput

Comment: Current output is [&#x20B9 50] but i want to show [₹ 50]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're assigning state values in the wrong way. This should be like:

```js
this.state = {
  Amount: 50,
  CurrencySymbol: "\u0024"
}
```

- `\u20B9` is used for rupee.
- `\u0024` is used for dollar.

And there is no state named `TAmount` in your states. You wrote `this.state.TAmount.toString()`. It should be `this.state.Amount.toString()`.

```js
<TextInput value={this.state.CurrencySymbol + " " + this.state.Amount.toString()} editable={false}></TextInput>
```

**Update**

Since you've `HTML` currency symbols, so you can save this by this way into your state:

```js
this.state = {
  Amount: 50,
  CurrencySymbol: "&#x20B9;",
  CurrencySymbols: {
    "&#x20B9;": "\u20B9",
    "&#x20AC;": "\u20AC",
    "&#x0024;": "\u0024"
  }
}

// Then use it on like this
<TextInput value={this.state.CurrencySymbols[this.state.CurrencySymbol] + " " + this.state.Amount.toString()} editable={false}></TextInput>
```

This can be the easiest way you would able to solve your problem I guess.

You can't use `HTML` like symbols in react native except in `react-native-webview`.

That's it.

Comment: I had changed the TAmount to Amount. my issue is not with amount. my issue with symbol code. i want to show the character of symbol using its code inside the TextInput

Comment: @vicky, I've updated my answer. If you would like to use currency symbol from the character, you need to use this way I've updated into my answer in the state's `CurrencySymbol`. `\u0024` this character is for `$`.

Comment: Here are the [currency symbols](https://aboutreact.com/react-native-currency-symbols/) for react native.

Comment: I am looking a solution with HTML character. i can not change api response.

Comment: How many symbols you would like to show, I can give an alternative solution to this.

Comment: @vicky, I've added an alternative solution to your problem. Have a look at that.

Comment: There is not possible to map every character.

Comment: You can create an array on which you can map these character you want and then import that into your file, and this can be done easily, by the way, I've already mentioned that you can't see HTML characters in react-native app. So you've to see those in a react-native way.

Answer (score 0):

Using state the way you are using is deprecated, you should either use `useState()` hook to define a state and its setter function.

**Update this**

```
import React,{ useState } from 'react';

//Set State Variables

const [amount,setAmount] = useState(50);
const [currencySymbol,setcurrencySymbol] = useState("&#x20B9;");

//Set value of text input to your state variable values

<TextInput value={currencySymbol + amount.toString()} editable={false} />
```